# Solution verification: Writing a sum in the Cantor normal form

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, set-theory, ordinals

Can someone please help with the following problem. I need to write the following sum in Cantor normal form:

$$\sum_{i ∈ ω\cdot2} \sum_{j ∈ i} (i+j)$$

The result I'm getting is $$ω^2 + w,$$ so I would like to check if it's correct.

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit to add:

My work:
$$\sum_{i ∈ ω\cdot2} \sum_{j ∈ i} (i+j) = \sum_{i ∈ ω} \sum_{j ∈ i} (i+j) + \sum_{i ∈ ω} \sum_{j ∈ i} (i+ω+j) = \sum_{i ∈ ω} \sum_{i∈j} (i+j+i+ω+j) = \sum_{i∈ ω} ( (i+0+i+ω+0)+(i+1+i+ω+1)+...+(i+i+i+ω+i)) = \\ sup_{n} \frac{2n(2n-1)}{2} + n\cdotω = ω^2 + ω$$

I'm not sure about the part that involves $$\frac{2n(2n-1)}{2}$$ I've concluded that the supremum for that is $$ω$$ but I'm not sure if that's correct

Comment: It would help if you put your work along with the question instead of just the end points. This way, people may see your thought process and identify possible mistakes.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion - I've edited the question to add that

Comment: @antenna The answer should be $\omega^3$. Basically you can plug-in a specific value of $i$ (removing the outer summation) and then try to see how the sum turns out to be.

Comment: okay, thank you very much for your answer!